# MathType Word Document export using MathPage MathML

Tags: html, ms-word, mathml, mathtype

I need to convert the ms-word 2003 documents to HTML with MathML included if there are math equations. The quick solution I found at the moment is using the MathType addin to export the whole document into a HTML with MathML using its "Publish to MathPage" function.

However, it couldn't do the conversion properly. Most of the equations in the document is still in the image format, instead of MathML. The strange thing is that it converts the commas into the MathML, not the equations.

The original word document:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4625393/test12.doc

The key part of the converted html source:
https://gist.github.com/katat/5091021

Is this a bug of the MathType?

Comment: @afwings It will be greatly appreciated if you can help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kata, I'm not sure what versions of Word and MathType you are using, but I was able to successfully create the MathPage with MathML. I am using Word 2013 and MathType 6.9. This is the page I created: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17008533/187.xht

Not sure what could have gone wrong with yours. It does seem that you chose an appropriate "target" for the MathPage; it looks like you chose XHTML+MathML.

If you can give me some more details about what steps you're taking from start to finish, I'll try to help more. Also let me know what versions of the software you're using.

Comment: I am using Office 2010 with MathType 6.7. Yes, I choose XHTML+MathML. Is it possible to do with the MathType version?

Comment: I don't understand your question "Is it possible to do with the MathType version?"

We've recently released MathType 6.9, with 2 new MathPage "targets" -- HTML+MathJax and XHTML+MathJax. Why don't you download the trial for MathType 6.9 and try the MathPage with the XHTML+MathJax option? It will produce MathML.